# How to get index of clicked element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have five anchor elements in my navigation. I want to get index of clicked element with jQuery. I tried this code.

```
$('.navigation ul li a').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var el = $(this).index();
  console.log(el);

 })
```

But every time I get zero in console.

https://jsfiddle.net/2hg2fkda/ fiddle is here.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.navigation ul li').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var el = $(this).index();
  console.log(el);

 })
```

Answer (score 4):

Index can be fetched if its list .
Replace your code here -

```
var el = $(this).parent().index();
```

**LIVE** https://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/hg0dqnxb/

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
$('.navigation ul li ').click(function (e) {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/2hg2fkda/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this!!

```
var el = $(this).closest('li').index();
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2hg2fkda/2/)**